# Datatables - ScrollX works on Firefox but does not work on Chrome

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, datatables

the problem is simple but I cannot find the solution. I have a datatable whose width is larger than its outer div.
The ScrollX bar appears in Firefox, but in Chrome it doesn't.

Does anybody know if there is any related bug and what is a possible fix?

The following codes within $("id").dataTable({}) were completely ineffective.

```
"bDestroy": true,
"sScrollX": "100%",
"bScrollCollapse": true,
```

Comment: I don't see any reason this would fail based on what you've given.  In that case, might I recommend pasting the entire `dataTable` function along with your html.  Also, it's entirely possible that something else is breaking your javascript in chrome so, if you haven't already, check the browser console output for errors.

Comment: ...in case you're new to the console: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JuVOwU0RcdA

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, just a matter of buffering I guess. I refreshed with F5 and everything was working fine